# Proxy settings in chrome are funky

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, proxy

I am running in Ubuntu 16.04. I have Chrome version:

```
Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

I have set the proxy settings system wide, and verified in `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` that they are ok:

```
Effective proxy settings
Proxy server for FTP: 127.0.0.1:1234
Proxy server for HTTP: 127.0.0.1:1234
Proxy server for HTTPS: 127.0.0.1:1234
Bypass list: 
  *localhost
  127.0.0.0/8
  *::1
Source: ENV
```

As expected.

Funnily, if I open a different Chrome profile and I check the proxy settings, the configuration is very different:

```
Effective proxy settings
PAC script: data:application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig;base64,dmFyIHBhY19lbmdpbmUgPSAoZnVuY3Rpb24gcXVpbmUoYnJvd3Nlcil7Cgp2YXIgRSA9IHt9OwovLyBYWFggc2hhY2hhcjogcmVtb3ZlIHRoaXMgYW5kIGV2ZXJ5dGhpbmcgdGhhdCB1c2VzIGl0CkUuZGVm...
```

1. Why does the config change from profile to profile?
2. How can I tell chrome to use the env config in this second profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the proxy settings with an extension, for example this [Proxy Switcher and Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switcher-and-manage/onnfghpihccifgojkpnnncpagjcdbjod/related?hl=en), which allows to set several proxy methods. It uses native Chrome API to set the proxy settings.

If you are using different Chrome profiles, you can install the plugin in each of your profiles, and manage your proxy settings for each profile.